# Open source BPM out of box notification feature

Tags: jbpm, activiti, business-process-management, camunda

I am trying to find whether JBPM or any other open source BPM softwares such as Camunda, Activiti has notification feature (i.e. email, mobile notifications) out of the box.

I am trying to find this in their documentation. However, I couldn't find much information.

If someone has used these tools, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Camunda does not provide such feature out of the box, but there are community extensions that provide some notification capabilities. You can find the full list of community extensions [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/introduction/extensions/).

Comment: Thanks @AskarAkhmerov! This is useful.

Comment: Activiti has an email task for basic notifications. Other scenarios can easily be implemented using listeners.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippeSevestre! Any pointer to the relevant documentation?

Comment: Take a look at the Activiti´s User Guide, item 8.5.6 - E-Mail Task and (https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnEmailTask). In order to work, you must add the required config parameters to the ProcessEngine configuration (https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnEmailTaskServerConfiguration).